# Applying function to a datapoint (coordinate-wise) in xarray

Tags: python-xarray

Let's say I have an xarray Dataset generated as `ds`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    r = pm.Uniform.dist(shape=100).eval(),
    h = pm.Normal.dist(3, 0.5, shape=100).eval(),
    t = range(100)
)).set_index('t')
    
ds = data.to_xarray()
```

As such, the `t` series becomes the coordinate, and there are two data variables (data arrays) `r` and `h`.

Now, let's say I have a function like:

```
def vol(r, h):
    return h * r ** 2 * np.pi
```

How do I apply this function to each data point in the xarray dataset, coordinate wise? In the end, I would like to have a data array with the same index (the coordinate `t`).

The the original pandas dataframe, to achieve the same result, I would do the following:

```
data.apply(lambda row: vol(row.r, row.h), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as:

```
ds["vol"] = ds["h"] * ds["r"] ** 2 * np.pi
```

See more in the docs here: https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#basic-array-math

Comment: Hi, this was more like a toy example, to demonstrate what I need to do. In general though, I would need to apply a function that I don't specifically control, and the structure of the xarray Dataset is a bit trickier.